# What does window do in nodejs

Tags: javascript, node.js, laravel, vue.js

I saw some codes in laravel's resources code, which I don't fully understand. these code lie in /sources/assets/js/app.js:

```
/**
 * First we will load all of this project's JavaScript dependencies which
 * includes Vue and other libraries. It is a great starting point when
 * building robust, powerful web applications using Vue and Laravel.
 */

require('./bootstrap');

window.Vue = require('vue');
```

I guess that require() is the node require(), but I don't know where the window comes form, since it's not a nodejs object. Can somebody enlighten me what's these codes for?

Comment: no window object in node

Comment: require works on frontend as well through some shim, in your case probably require.js.

Comment: Since bootstrap is a client-side framework, this must be code that runs in the browser so `window` is the browser-based `window` object and this code is not running in node.js.  `require()` here is some other library that loads code in the browser, not the node.js `require()`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The code is running on the front-end, so we can rule it either of the two variable being a node variable.

In Laravel's case, require is coming from [Browserify](https://github.com/substack/node-browserify).

"window" is a JavaScript object on the client side. By assigning window.Vue, they're making the variable global so it can be accessed anywhere on the frontend. You can read more about the window variable [here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window)

Comment: I saw the word "webpack" in webpack.mix.js in lavarel's root directory, does it mean anything to require()? 'cause I didn't see a browserify in lavarel.